# How to call a page virtually in php?

Tags: php

is there a way in php to call a page virtually?

I got my analytics code in

www.domain.com/somepage.php

I want to call this page when executing a function inside another page.

Now i am not talking about iframe or echo. I mean virtual load.

Comment: what do you really mean? what is the expected result?

Comment: That's a lame way for increasing your page views :) Or are you talking about "Inlcuding"?

Comment: Please elaborate the question

Comment: well there is a page inside i have some tracking code (i can not add tracking dirctly inside the function page) then there is  another folder inside i have my function files, in one of the files there is a function from which i want to call this tracking file virtually.

Comment: if you mean just parsing without output, then just make sure your script doesn't generate any output (print/echo) and u r fine by using include. as per ur comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by "virtual" load.

If you want to include a php script in your php pages, you can use the include function :

```
<?php
// Include and execute what's inside somefile.php
inclucde 'somefile.php';

// Your code here
```

Comment: Hi,i mean parsing virtually.

Comment: @JoniJeni So, an include should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "download" by virtual you can use `file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/page")`